# Primary key and unique key seperate exception handling | asp .net c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am using following code to handle exceptions for Unique key and primary key violation.

```
catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Number == 2627)
            {
                if (ex.Message.Contains("Unique"))
                    //error msg regarding Unique key violation.
                else
                    //error msg regarding Primary key violation.
            }
            else
                    //any other error msg.
}
```

But it is not working properly. For both primary key and unique key violation same error message (error msg of primary key) displays.

When I simply display error messages whithout using

```
if (ex.Number == 2627)
                {
                    if (ex.Message.Contains("Unique"))
                        //error msg regarding Unique key violation.
                    else
                        //error msg regarding Primary key violation.
                }
                else
```

following error messages are shown:

```
For Primary key:
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_users'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.users'. The statement has been terminated.
```

and

```
For Unique key:
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__users__AB6E61640425A276'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.users'. The statement has been terminated.
```

Please suggest any solution for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Contains method is case sensitive. You should be using

```
catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Number == 2627)
        {
            if (ex.Message.Contains("UNIQUE"))
                //error msg regarding Unique key violation.
            else
                //error msg regarding Primary key violation.
        }
        else
                //any other error msg.
}
```